# Create table valued function with cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my first table valued function.

I have a table call `tableFunc`

My table contains the following columns:

- `Empid` (23610, 23611...) -- unique
- `ChDate` (2015-4-21 22:02:10.807, 2015-4-21 22:02:11.050,...)
- `Site` (25)--all the same value
- `userid` (7,7,...) --all the same value
- `initsal` (0, 0,...) --all the same value
- `finsal` (0.696176161, 0.696176161,...)--all the same value
- `note` (enter text, enter text...) --all the same value

I would like to create a table valued function with a cursor that would fetch through the rows and return only unique records. I'm open to other suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS (Oracle, MySQL, etc) are you using? Have you considered `SELECT DISTINCT`, and if not, why not?

Comment: I'm using SQL Sever.  I am trying to use this table with other tables to create a view and when doing so I get duplicate records. so SELECT DISTINCT did not work.

Comment: Well actually they aren't duplicates because ChDate is different... Do you want just the other columns that aren't duplicates?

Comment: Stephan, yes I'd like to be able to fetch through this table and return the rows that are not duplicates.

Comment: Try to **avoid** cursors if you can - and in 99% of cases, *you can!*

Comment: Stephen, I get the following error when I run the last query: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0):

This will select distinct values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Empid,
                [Site],
                userID,
                initsal,
                finsal,
                note
FROM tableFunc A
GROUP BY Empid,[Site],userID,initsal,finsal,note
```

If you want the distinct EmpIDs with a list of chDates:

```
SELECT  Empid,
        STUFF   (
                (
                SELECT ',' + CAST(chDate AS VARCHAR(30))
                FROM tableFunc SubQuery
                WHERE SubQuery.Empid = A.Empid
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ),
                1,1,'') AS ChDateList,
        [Site],
        userID,
        initsal,
        finsal,
        note,
        MAX(chDate) AS recent_chDate
FROM tableFunc A
GROUP BY Empid,[Site],userID,initsal,finsal,note
```

Comment: Stephan, I get the following error when I run the last query: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Stephan, nice and Ican confirm there are no duplicates, how can I tell sql to return the most recent chDate in report.

Comment: I added the column recent_chDate

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can write a table valued function to get unique records from the tablefunc table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetUniqueRecords() 
RETURNS @TableFunc TABLE (
    --I am not sure how you have these datatypes defined, but change it to your needs
    EmpId INT NOT NULL
    ,ChDate datetime
    ,Site INT
    ,userid INT
    ,initsal MONEY
    ,finsal MONEY
    ,note VARCHAR(200)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT into @TableFunc(EmpId,ChDate,Site,userid,initsal,finsal,note)
    SELECT Empid
        ,max(ChDate)
        ,max([Site])
        ,max(userID)
        ,max(initsal)
        ,max(finsal)
        ,max(note)
    FROM tableFunc
    GROUP BY Empid;

    RETURN;
END
GO
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Rookie13, thank you. I updated my code to reflect yours. Now is it possible to add a cursor that can fetch through the rows and return the most recent record(s) possibly by date and time.

Comment: Wonderful! I am glad that it helped. If I understand correctly, the function above should already bring you the most recent record based on your ChDate. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: There was an extra comma after the ChDate datetime. I removed that, can you please try it again?

Comment: The initial table contains 747 rows.  And when I run the function, I get the same amount of records.

Comment: Does your tableFunc table has multiple rows for same EmpId? If we don't have multiple ids, you will always return a distinct set of records. Otherwise, this function should return back any employees that has duplicate records.

Comment: the Id are not duplicateS, they are uniqued (Id INT (IDENTITY (1,1))

Comment: Hmm interesting...I am wondering how the records would not be unique already in your tablefunc table?